# Difference in Line-Height in IE9 within TextAreas

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, textarea

I have a `TEXTAREA` where spacing is very important. I formatted it as follows:

```
TEXTAREA {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial; 
  font-size: 8pt; 
  letter-spacing: 0px; 
  line-height: 13px;
}
```

How, if I enter some text, the line height is not correctly applied: The last line of every paragraph (before pessing enter or shift-enter) is one pixel to high:

[image: Annotated Screenshot]

This problem only occurs in Internet Explorer 9, not in Firefox 7 or Chrome 14 (haven't tested older versions so far).

Is there a way to get rid of thad?

BTW: It does not happen for the last line of the textarea, unless there is a linebreak behind it.

Regards,
  Steffen

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not actually help entirely nor be the full answer, but it may be worth while reading up a little on the use of `!important` declaration within CSS.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

The only reason why this springs to mind is there may be another style/declaration that is applied after which is causing some sort of problem and this will make sure your textarea has the correct styles applied to it.

You may also want to check that any `<p>` CSS declarations are not causing conflicts/problems with any bottom or top margin's/paddings? Same goes with span or any other styles that could potentially cause some sort of problems.

Like I said, I'm aware this may not help in the slightest but it could be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with the last line in a textarea in IE8.  When my textarea had a line-height of less than 18px, the cursor changed the line-height.  The reason I bring this up is your line-height of 13px is quite small.  You may want to experiment with larger line-heights to see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I just went many many rounds with this issue and finally discovered that IE9 is adding extra padding to textareas.  Line height, height, etc had no effect.  This did the trick:

```
padding: 0px !important;
```